# Use table of column metadata as column header and type

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Tables

---

dbo.Metadata:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| ID | int |
| Name | varchar(50) |
| Location | varchar(50) |

dbo.Data:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Awesomenauts Inc. | Germany |
| 2 | DataMunchers | France |
| 3 | WeBuyStuff | France |

Wanted Output:

| ID | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Awesomenauts Inc. | Germany |
| 2 | DataMunchers | France |
| 3 | WeBuyStuff | France |

Is there any simple way to achieve this?
Perhaps with Dynamic SQL?

Oh, and the schema may wary from day to day, everything will be batch reloaded into the DWH daily.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have some sort of order defined in your metadata for this to work. For my script, I added ColumnOrder for reference

```
/*Setup Metadata table*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Metadata
CREATE TABLE #Metadata (
    ColumnOrder INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY /*Need to have some sort of defined column order, I created one for illustration purposes*/
    ,[Column] SYSNAME
    ,[Type] VARCHAR(255)
)
/*Load data*/
INSERT INTO #Metadata
VALUES 
('ID','int')
,('Name','varchar(50)')
,('Location','varchar(50)')

/*Create dynamic SQL*/
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

/*Create column list*/
;WITH cte_Column AS (
    SELECT ColumnOrder,
        [Column]
        ,[Type]
        ,DataColName = CONCAT('Col',Row_Number () OVER (ORDER BY A.ColumnOrder))
    FROM #Metadata AS A
)

SELECT @DynamicSQL 
    = STRING_AGG(
        Concat(QUOTENAME([Column])
            ,' = CAST ('
            ,DataColName
            ,' AS '
            ,A.[Type]
            ,')')
            ,CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(10),',') /*Line break + comma separators*/
        )
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.ColumnOrder) /*Ensures columns concatenated in order*/
FROM cte_Column AS A

Set @DynamicSQL = CONCAT('SELECT ',@DynamicSQL,CHAR(13),CHAR(10),' FROM dbo.Data')

PRINT @DynamicSQL

/*Uncomment to execute*/
--EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```